# Can't create conda environments due to Conda OpenSSL Error (M1 chip)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, apple-m1

I keep running into the following issue when I try to create conda environments on my computer which has an M1 chip.:

```bash
CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/osx-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

However, I do have the SSL module installed (typing "openssl version" in command line yields OpenSSL 1.1.1v.). Some stackexchange solutions suggest copying .dll files, but none of these files suggested exist for me. How can I resolve this?

[I'm a beginner with conda and computer troubleshooting, I appreciate simple answers!]

Comment: I have a Macbook Pro with an M1 chip.  I run Python and Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm and manage dependencies with virtual environments.  Works well for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.